# Cannot save to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a view to display data from the database

```
public ActionResult UpdateDetail()
    {
        using (UsersDatabaseEntities ude = new UsersDatabaseEntities())
        {
            ude.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            return View(ude.Users.Where(a => a.Email == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
```

Then, I tried to edit and save to database

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateDetail([Bind(Exclude = "IsEmailVerified,ActivationCode")] User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (UsersDatabaseEntities ude = new UsersDatabaseEntities())
            {
                ude.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                ude.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

The problem is, it seems to not be saved to the database. i tried to call UpdateDetail again, and it shows the data do not saved.

I do not find syntax error.

does the data truly saved?

Comment: Have you debugged your code (is `ModelState` valid)?

Comment: ModelState is valid. i managed to retrieve the data and display on View,  but when save button is clicked, no changes occur. no syntax errors whatsoever, only the data is not saved.

Comment: So you saying when you put a breakpoint on `if (ModelState.IsValid)` it is executing the code in the `if` block (I find that hard to believe)?

Comment: You need to do some debugging. "seems not to" is not a satisfactory description of the problem, it reveals you haven't done enough investigation. The code _looks_ like it would work, and we can't see any of your data, or your table structure, or your model values, or the variable values during execution, or your error log. Those are things only you can check. Check them, if you still don't understand what's happening, tell us the results of your debugging and maybe we can help more. So far we do not have enough information

Comment: P.S. you said " when save button is clicked, no changes occur. no syntax errors whatsoever". Do you know what a syntax error is? If a syntax error happens then your code doesn't compile and doesn't run at all. You can't get a syntax error while the code is executing. You can get runtime errors, but not syntax errors. I suggest you learn the difference, or at least learn to use the correct terminology.

Answer (score -4):

Add the debugger inside your **UpdateDetail** action and also write the if(ModelState.IsValid){ //..logic goes there } else{ return View();} check the modelstate don't have any error then try to update User and seem like it's happen when we have some non-nullable field and passing to the null values into them.

Comment: what's up the condition is not working or should i provide you another procedure. ?